# checkmark sign Tableview Automatic make

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

its one mandatory.the problem is the checkmark sign by default move down to 11 paces. so if you have 9 item in a list, you see that not happening with 9 item in a list. but if you have 30 item in a list, you will see 3 checkmark.but it should be one which one i have `choice?.isSelect == true`

```
if  choice?.isSelect == true {
  //this code execute one time              
  print("===========Checkmark=================")

  cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

}
```

One point out : tableview its reuse privious cell so if cell has already checked then 11th cell automatic checked.  how can i fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps due to re-usability previously added check mark remains on the cell. Try like this:

```
if  choice?.isSelect == true {
  //this code execute one time              
  print("===========Checkmark=================")

  cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

}
else
{
  cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Comment: my brain not working .. that's the reason i did not fix this issue . thanks

Comment: `isSelect` is a Boolean so you can do `if  choice?.isSelect {` (no need for `== true`) this is better semantically, reads like English. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just put else condition

```
if  choice?.isSelect == true {
    //this code execute one time              
    print("===========Checkmark=================")

     cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

  }else{
     cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
```

Comment: both answered at same time @nazmul